# Remove a part of string containing another field in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, replace

I need to remove a part of string in one column corresponding to another column.
I know I can use the REPLACE function for that, but not sure how to use it.

So, in my case, I want to remove the first part of the "name" column that is the same as the winery column.

Example:

```
Name: Family Wines Vintage Special
Winery: Family Wines
```

I want to obtain:

```
Name: Vintage Special
Winery: Family Wines
```

Possible problems:

- the function needs to do nothing if Name and Winery are the same.
- don't keep the space at begin of Name field after removing
- if possible, clean the Name string if starts with coma (') or semicolon (;) after the removing OR use another query for that

Something like that:

```
UPDATE usr_wines SET name=REPLACE(name, winery, '') WHERE name LIKE '%' || winery;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a character from the beginning of a text value, use the [substr() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
UPDATE usr_wines
SET Name = substr(Name, 2)
WHERE Name LIKE ',%';
```

The same can be done with a dynamic string:

```
UPDATE usr_wines
SET Name = substr(Name, length(Winery) + 1)
WHERE Name LIKE Winery || '%'
  AND Name != Winery;
```

Comment: That's really a great answer ! Thanks a lot !